# JSON Schema - conditionally required field based on number of values in another property

Tags: jsonschema

I have a thresholds property which is required but only if number of elements in the new prices array is greater than 1.

What is the best way of achieving this?

I know you could add if/then statement or alloff etc but I really don't know how to do it and any help would be much appreciated

```
{
    "schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema",
    "type": "object",
    "required": [
        "id",
    ],
    "properties": {
        "id": {
            "type": "string",
            "maxLength": 50,
            "minLength": 1,
            "title": "ID",
            "readOnly": true
        },
        "description": {
            "type": "string",
            "nullable": true,
            "title": "Description"
        },
        "allItems": {
            "type": "array",
            "title": "All Items",
            "items": {
                "required": [
                    "prices",
                ],
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "prices": {
                        "type": "array",
                        "maxItems": 8,
                        "title": "Test Prices",
                        "items": {
                            "required": [
                                "newPrices",
                                "thresholds"
                            ],
                            "type": "object",
                            "properties": {
                                "newPrices": {
                                    "type": "array",
                                    "title": "New Prices",
                                    "maxItems": 4,
                                    "minItems": 1,
                                    "items": {
                                        "type": "number",
                                        "format": "double"
                                    },
                                },
                                "thresholds": {
                                    "type": "array",
                                    "maxItems": 3,
                                    "title": "Thresholds",
                                    "items": {
                                        "type": "integer",
                                        "format": "int32"
                                    },
                                }
                            },
                            "additionalProperties": false
                        },
                    }
                },
                "additionalProperties": false
            },
            "nullable": true
        },
    "additionalProperties": false
});
```

Comment: can you share an example of a passing schema and a failing schema?

Answer (score 0):

The way you have your schema written now is effectively enforcing `thresholds` and `newPrices` to always be defined. Your use of `minItems: 1` on the `newPrices` array guarantees the array cannot be 0 items.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy. I understand that but I need to update the schema to have a condition which checks if newPrices array has minItems = 2 and if it does then make threshold required field otherwise leave it as not mandatory.

Comment: afaik, JSON Schema cannot evaluate other properties in this manner.  You can check if the minItems value is 2 as a constraint, but it can't decipher the number of items in an array at runtime to apply constraints against another property